# How to set credentials in bindings file for JMSInput Node

Tags: binding, rabbitmq, ibm-integration-bus

I am using the JMSInput node in an IIB flow to connect with Rabbitmq. Locally it's working fine with a binding file, but how/where to set login credentials for a remote rabbitmq server?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JMS Node and create your own JMSProviders in configurable services.

Comment: Hi Harsha, could you please elaborate?